# Contradiction between confidence intervals and z-test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, z-test

I've got a problem with $z$-test and confidence intervals. The $z$-test rejects the null hypothesis (proportions are equal), but the confidence intervals are intersect.

Let us consider 2 companies. The proportion of smokers in company $A$ is $p(A)=0.22$. And the proportion of smokers in company $B$ is $p(B)=0.303$. The amount of employees in company $A$ is $403$. And the amount of employees in company $B$ is $404$.

So, we have the following data:
\begin{align}
p(A)&=0.22  &n(A)&=403  \\
p(B)&=0.303 &n(B)&=404
\end{align}

Now let's apply the $z$-test by the following formula for proportions (I took the formula from [here](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/268)):

$$z= \frac{p(B)-p(A)}{\sqrt{p(1-p)(\frac{1}{n(A)}+\frac{1}{n(b)})}}$$

Where $p$ is $$p=\frac{p(A)n(A)+p(B)n(B)}{n(A)+n(B)}$$

I made the following computation:
$$p=\frac{0.22*403+0.303*404}{403+404}=0.2614$$

$$z= \frac{0.303-0.22}{\sqrt{0.2614(1-0.2614)(\frac{1}{403}+\frac{1}{404})}}=2.6828$$

So, $z$ more than $1.96$, it means that we reject the null hypothesis. The proportions $p(A)$ and $p(B)$ are not equal.

But then I've computed the 95% confidence intervals by the following formulas (I took them from [here](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat200/node/48)):

\begin{align} \newcommand{\low}{{\rm low}}  \newcommand{\high}{{\rm high}}
\low  &= P-1.96 \sqrt{\frac{P(1-P)}{N}}  \\
\high &= P+1.96 \sqrt{\frac{P(1-P)}{N}}
\end{align}
Where $P$ is proportion of smokers in some company and $N$ is amount of employees in this company.

I've computed the interval for company $A$:
\begin{align}
\low(A) &= p(A)-1.96 \sqrt{\frac{p(A)(1-p(A))}{n(A)}} = 0.22-1.96 \sqrt{\frac{0.22*0.78}{403}} = 0.1796  \\
\high(A) &= p(A)+1.96 \sqrt{\frac{p(A)(1-p(A))}{n(A)}} = 0.22+1.96 \sqrt{\frac{0.22*0.78}{403}} = 0.2604
\end{align}
So, for $p(A)$ the CI is $(0.1796;0.2696)$.

And finally I've computed the interval for the company $B$:
\begin{align}
\low(B) &= p(B)-1.96 \sqrt{{p(B)(1-p(B))}{n(B)}} = 0.303-1.96 \sqrt{\frac{0.303 * 0.697}{404}} = 0.2581  \\
\high(B) &= p(B)+1.96 \sqrt{{p(B)(1-p(B))}{n(B)}} = 0.303+1.96 \sqrt{\frac{0.303 * 0.697}{404}} = 0.3477
\end{align}
For $p(B)$ the confidence interval is $(0.2581; 0.3477)$.

And now we see that confidence intervals are intersect, but it contradicts the computations for $z$-test.

Finally I've used a web service for computing the $z$-test and the CI. The service drew the intersection of the CI's and rejected the null hypothesis of the $z$-test, too.

What is the cause of the contradiction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing the confidence interval portion of your analysis incorrectly.

Your null hypothesis is $H_{o}: p_1 = p_2$. This hypothesis is about the *difference in proportions* between company A and company B. However, for confidence intervals you computed two one-sample confidence intervals for company A and company B, and then looked for an overlap. This is not the same thing as a confidence interval for the difference in proportions. The <strike>droids</strike> formula you're looking is:

$ \hat{p}_{2} - \hat{p}_{1} \pm Z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}} \sqrt{ \frac{\hat{p}_{1}(1-\hat{p}_{1})}{n_1} + \frac{\hat{p}_{2}(1-\hat{p}_{2})}{n_2} } $

Substituting the appropriate values for a 95% confidence interval yields (0.022, 0.143), which agrees with the hypothesis test.

The CI for the difference is directly looking at what we are interested in: the difference between the proportions for companies A and B. Using two 1-sample CIs is an indirect means of comparison. If they *didn't* overlap, we could conclude that the two proportions *did* differ, but the opposite isn't true: their overlap tells us absolutely nothing about whether the two proportions differ. Two groups can show overlapping confidence intervals, and yet be significantly different when a two-sample procedure is used.

[This](http://www.graphpad.com/support/faqid/1362/) link and [this](http://blog.minitab.com/blog/real-world-quality-improvement/common-statistical-mistakes-you-should-avoid) link discuss this issue a bit.

And two other things:

- Just a typo, but for future reference, hypothesis has a "y", not an "i".
- I'm not sure if this was a typo or a misunderstanding: The confidence level you used was 95%, not 5%. Your hypothesis test was conducted at the 5% *level of significance*, the confidence interval was at 95% *confidence*.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! What's the distinction between the two one-sample confidence intervals and the confidence interval of the difference? I don't understand why the computation of the two one-sample confidence intervals is wrong way.

Comment: These two things are my typos. Thank you, I'll correct them.

Comment: Is this not also one of the classic cases where you can get a discrepancy between test & CI? For the CI you need a variance estimate that is valid under the alternative, for the test only one that is valid under the null hypothesis.

Comment: @Björn Thanks for the reminder, I actually had the wrong standard error, I used the standard error for the hypothesis test, not for the confidence interval.

Comment: @facelesswanderer I added a bit into the answer to address that, it was getting a bit long for a comment.

Answer (score 1):

### Confidence $\neq$ probability !

The apparent contradiction comes from an erroneous understanding of confidence intervals.

0.95 is the probability that the sampling *procedure* will provide a sample such that the confidence interval that can be computed with that sample will overlap the true value of the parameter. That .95 probability is therefore only relevant *before the sample is drawn*, not after. You cannot say that "the probability for the parameter to be in the confidence interval is 95%" once the interval is known (just like, once a coin has been tossed and turned up Heads, you cannot say it has probability 1/2 of being Tails, although that was true just before tossing it). This is why it is called a *confidence* interval and not a probable interval.

BTW, even if it were true that both intervals had a .95 chance of containing the parameter, as they are independent their intersection would have probability $.95^2$.